The Expanding Menagerie of Station 17 Analog SF&F
Trying to find a copy and the author of a story published in Analog in the 80s or early 90s called "The Expanding Menagerie of Station 17," wherein more and more animals are ordered by a space station to control the infestations of the previously ordered animals.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How confident are you in the title?  I can't find anything similar at ISFDb regardless of decade or source.

Nothing remotely familiar shows up here https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Works_originally_published_in_Analog_Science_Fiction_and_Fact&pagefrom=Robots+Have+No+Tails#mw-pages but I'm not sure how exhaustive the list is.  A google search fails to match the exact phrase.

"There was a space station that swallowed a fly..."

Wow. Thanks to everyone for your attempts. Buzz is on point, because what got me thinking about the story was that nursery rhyme, which I was thinking of because of a discussion about using house spiders to control fruit flies.
When I search for the story, the googlety AI comes up with a plot, characters, Arlo Jensen and Maya, and more. But there is no reference to the author or where such a story was published.

Even more wow.
When I went through my search history to find the AI entry, what came up was a nearly identical entry, but with different character names. The AI created a summary of the story for me, without any such story actually existing???

Yes, AIs do that :-) They are mostly useless for finding any but the most obvious stories.

I'm pretty certain this story has been asked about here already, though I haven't found it so far. But I suspect you have misremembered the title since the ISFDB lists no stories with similar titles to yours.

I think the title was created by the AI.
I really do recall a story about an asteroid-dweller who ends up ordering larger and larger animals. The AI sent me down the wrong track, however.
I was thinking about it because I was discussing when colonists come to a new place and bring their rats, etc, with them, and the rats take over. Then the colonists decide to bring in cats to eat the rats, etc. etc.
Though, a story based on what the AI cobbled together could be pretty entertaining and thoughtful.

Does it end with the guy sitting on the outside of the asteroid awaiting rescue, having been driven out by the successive waves of "vermin"? I've been trying to prod my vague memories of the story into life and I think I remember this scene.

John Rennie - I think so.
